# Google Chart BackgroundColor

Tags: json, google-visualization

I'm trying to change backgroundColor.fill to set it transparent but it accept only on firebug, not working on var options...

Can someone help me?

```
var options = {
            backgroundColor: {
                fill: 'transparent'
            },
            chart: {
                title: 'Termômetro de Economia',
                subtitle: 'Algar Agro'
            },
            bars: 'vertical' // Required for Material Bar Charts.
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to use:

```
chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
```

instead:

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```